# cant scrub forwards or back on videos on SharePoint

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, video

I can't seem to get video files in sharePoint 2013 to allow you to scrub ahead or back.

this happens if files are in a video library or a normal doc library.

Chrome doesn't seem to work at all the video will just play and not let you scrub forward or back

IE will let you click to where you wan't but seems to need to download the whole file up to where you you have selected then will let you jump backward.

Has anyone got some solutions for this.

edit example of what happens in chrome: https://i.imgur.com/VbU66VD.gifv

Edit: Ive also just figured out that chrome will let me scrub back and forth but only if the video has buffered the whole video.

Most videos are to long for this as they will only buffer a small chuck at a time.

Comment: I upload a .mp4 video to the Asset library and normal library, it will open the video in Microsoft video player in IE11, open in the up to date Chrome directly,I can scrub forwards or back on videos via progress bar. I am afraid I couldn't reproduce your issue, please provide more information such as screentshots.

Comment: @juli_MSFT i've uploaded an example of what happens

Comment: Have you clear the browser cache and compare the result?

Comment: @julie_MSFT clear the cache makes no difference

Comment: @julie_MSFT I've just worked out that you can scrub in chrome but only if you let the whole video load first which will not happen on most video that's are over a specific length